# Фатальная ошибка в методе getHour()

Tags: android

Хочу создать простенький будильник, не могу понять, почему приложение вылетает при вызове строки `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());`. Вроде всё сделано по инструкциям.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button button;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Calendar calendar;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timpik);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpik);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());

    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит Layout файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.administrator.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timpik"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bpik"
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во-первых добавьте текст вашей ошибки не картинкой а текстом, во-вторых покажите 30 строку, и добавьте информации, иначе вопрос будет закрыт из-за проблем с качеством

Comment: вы не добавили текст ошибки в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование этого метода зависит от того какая версия android используется. Есть такой вариант решения вашей ошибки:

```
int hour = 0;
int min = 0;

int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
    hour = timePicker1.getHour();
    min = timePicker1.getMinute();
} else {
    hour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
    min = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
}
```

Вот есть [вопрос_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264156/how-to-replace-old-getcurrenthour-with-new-gethour/32267585#32267585) и так же [статья_1](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.TimePicker/getCurrentMinute) и [статья_2](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.TimePicker/getCurrentHour) для возможного решения вашей проблемы.

Comment: понятно, спасибо